# Unbind ng-models inside ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following issue, I generate several forms using ng-repeat,
I use ng-model to capture the textarea values and it works perfectly but when I try to write something on the textarea elements inside the forms generated by the ng-repeat the text is being duplicated  inside  all the textarea elements at the same time.

[image]

is there some way to Unbind those ng-models?

```
<div ng-repeat="PostList in PostList">
  <form id="PostFormComments" role="form">
      <div class="row input-field">
        <textarea data-ng-model="data.newComment" placeholder="write  something?...." type=text></textarea>
       </div>
       <a name="action" ng-disabled="!data.newComment" data-ng-click="addCommentPost();" ng-class="clear" class="secondary-content btn-floating waves-effect waves-light  light-blue darken-2"></a>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use `$index` which gives you the index of the current `ng-repeat` and create an object and access it via that.

So you would do something like: `$scope.data = {}`

and then you'd have the form like:

```
<div ng-repeat="PostList in PostList">
  <form id="PostFormComments" role="form">
      <div class="row input-field">
        <textarea data-ng-model="data[$index].newComment" placeholder="write  something?...." type=text></textarea>
       </div>
       <a name="action" ng-disabled="!data[$index].newComment" data-ng-click="addCommentPost();" ng-class="clear" class="secondary-content btn-floating waves-effect waves-light  light-blue darken-2"></a>
  </form>
  </div>
```

and you would see different textarea `ng-models` as governed by its `$index`.

Comment: That's it! thank you! 
 data-ng-click="addCommentPost($index);"                                              JS:                                                                                                   $scope.data = {};
$scope.addCommentPost = function(index) {
 var comment = $scope.data[index].newComment;              console.log(comment);   }